# How do you store FB api response?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am trying the following code.  I want the `html.concat(name)` line to work.  `html` is a string.

```
  function getName() {                                                      
    var name = fbName(function(name){                                         
      alert(html);  //works                                                        
      alert("getName: " + name);  //works
      html.concat(name);  //fails?                                   
      alert(html);  // failed: html remains unchanged                                            
    });                                                                     
  };                                                                          

  function fbName(callback){                                                  
    FB.api('/' + user_id + '?fields=name', function(response) {             
      callback(response.name);                                                
    });                                                                     
  };                                                                        
  getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings in js are immutable so `html.concat(name);` does not modify the value of  `html` but returns a new string.
use `html = html.concat(name);` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the String information.  How do I then change the html variable already defined?

Comment: @MartinVelez `html = html.concat(name);`